# How to declare dynamic state values in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create text inputs in a loop.

```
loop... {
    return <TextInput value={this.state.WHAT-TO-USE-HERE} />
}
```

As you can see I don't know how to dynamically set where text input will be in state? 

In JSX I have:

```
render() { ...
  list.map((item, index) => {
   return this.createTextInput(item);
...
```

Function that create inputs:

```
createTextInput(item) {
  return (
    <TextInput value={this.state.XYZ} ... />
  )
}
```

Comment: You need to use `[ ] `

Comment: Can you post the whole code? You can't loop (while/for) inside JSX.

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: Is there a reason you need every item individually in the state? why not just have the whole array in state and update that which will re-render the list. Also for lists you might want to use flatlist for better performance.

Comment: I don't use list I put one bellow other in <View/>. I need to have key: value stored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
const dynamicVar = 'test';

loop... {
    return <TextInput value={this.state[dynamicVar]} />
}
```

**Edit: As your question is clearer, here is the updated answer**

You should have `This is a test` in your input as value.

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {list.map((item, index) => (
          <TextInput
            value = { this.state[item.id] }
            onChange = {(event) => this.setState({ [item.id]: event.target.value })}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Does it make sense or do you need more details ?

Comment: Can you provide example. I tried to put this.state['someUniqueName'] doesn't show in state. And I also tried to set it in function that create inputs as state but this crash app.

Comment: Edited the answser according to your edited question

Answer (score -2):

How about this (untested)

```js
state={ change: {} }

handleChange = idx => {

this.setState(change[idx]: e.target.value )
}

loop... {
    return <TextInput onChange={()=> handleChange(idx)} value={this.state.change.idx} />
}
```